# How to create a terminal with a horizontal split in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tooling

This seems quite basic, but I can only seem to create vertical splits in vs code, and would like to be able to create horizontal but don't know what the command is to do so.

I have tried looking through the commands prefixed with `Terminal:` , but don't seem to have anything that will create a new terminal in a horizontal split. The command that I'm using to create a new terminal is `Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal`

Answer (score 31):

open a first terminal, then a second one, then right click a terminal: "move to editor area".

Comment: Yes, I like this: Once the terminal window is in the editor area, instead of the pane, you can arrange it with the other editors however you like!

The command is available for binding to a key: `Terminal: Move Terminal into Editor Area`

Answer (score 9):

### Configure default terminal location

In theory you can configure the terminal location, using `Workbench > Panel: Default Location`:

[image]

The setting ID is `workbench.panel.defaultLocation`

The JSON is:

```
"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "left"
```

That doesn't work for me. Sounds like a bug.

### Work-around

To work around this you can:

1. Pull up a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>
2. Right click on the `TERMINAL` tab
3. Select either "Move panel left" or "Move panel right"
4. Click into the panel
5. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> to split the terminal
6. You now have two terminals, one above the other

Comment: thanks, but i wanted to be able to have my code above / below the terminal

Comment: Two terminals, one above the other, both below the code window?

Comment: ideally - i would like the option of putting a terminal anywhere a split can be made. At the moment it seems that I'm only able to place a terminal to the right of the code, in a vertical split, which isn't what I would like. An example of placing a terminal where I would like is for there to be a horizontal split, where one split contains code and the other contains a terminal. I would assume that, if this was possible, further splits could also be achieved, but for now I would like to be able to do this.

Comment: @baxx were you able to figure out how to have it both ways? By both ways, I mean having the panel on the right and being able to split the terminal vertically as opposed to horizontally to vice versa?

Comment: i gave up on using terminal in vscode and just shift tab to iterm now

Answer (score 4):

On the terminal panel click on Configure Terminal Settings
[image: On the terminal panel click on Configure Terminal Settings]

On the next screen change Default Location to editor
[image: On the next screen change Default Location to editor]

Now if you create terminals it will create it in editor window

Answer (score 3):

I have also found that changing the alignment of the terminal panel can give some more width and prevent crammed text in a narrow terminal column. To do this go into the VSCode menu...

`View` -> `Appearance` -> `Align Panel` -> `Justify`

This will place the terminal below everything and give extra width because it is no longer crowded by the Primary Side Bar.

Comment: This is the one that works for VSCode. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use tmux and use ITerm.app in your configuration

[image]

Comment: I'm curoius, what advantage does iTerm.app bring inside VSCode on OS X ?
Also: here is a search link to splitting windows in Tmux, for those new to it: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tmux+split

Comment: I found this to be very unhandy. You can't click inside the desired terminal and you need to learn the various keyboard combinations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and your cat walked on your keyboard and opened a split terminal somehow, you can close it by right clicking the split piece and select `Kill Terminal`.